# Login test not working with ArgumentCaptor

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-testing

I have been struggling with ArgumentCaptor since a week, and cant find any resource or what is happening.

Simply I want to test if an user can login to my app, I do this by just calling the presenter method `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)` , and then verifiy if the interactor callback is executed to verify it was succefully logged in, but every time I run the test I get this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: callbackCaptor.capture() must not be null
```

### Presenter

```
override fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {
    view?.showProgress()
    signInInteractor.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, object : SignInInteractor.SignInCallBack {

        override fun onSuccess() {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                view?.navigateToMain()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(errormsg: String) {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                view?.hideProgress()
                view?.showError(errormsg)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

### PresenterTest

```
@Captor
private lateinit var callbackCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<SignInInteractor.SignInCallBack>

@Mock
lateinit var view: LoginContract.View

@Mock
lateinit var interactor:SignInInteractor

@InjectMocks
lateinit var presenter: LoginPresenter

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    presenter.attachView(view)
}

@Test
fun shouldLoginIn(){
    presenter.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test4@gmail.com","asdasd")
    verify(interactor,times(1)).signInWithEmailAndPassword("test4@gmail.com","asdasd",callbackCaptor.capture())
    callbackCaptor.value.onSuccess()
    verify(view,times(1)).navigateToMain()
}
```

### SignInCallback

```
interface SignInInteractor {

    interface SignInCallBack {
        fun onSuccess()
        fun onFailure(errormsg:String)
    }

    fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email:String,password:String,listener:SignInCallBack)
}
```

And my

### Interactor

```
override fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email:String, password:String, listener: SignInInteractor.SignInCallBack) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance()?.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                listener.onSuccess()
            } else { 
                listener.onFailure(it.exception.message)
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is at my test, is not letting me check if the parameters I executed the method `signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)` returns onSuccess()

[image: Test Error]

Error is at this line

```
verify(interactor,times(1)).signInWithEmailAndPassword("test4@gmail.com","asdasd",callbackCaptor.capture())
```

PD: I already have asserted with no-null the `ArgumentCaptor` but is not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [*mockito-kotlin*](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) for writing the tests in *Kotlin*.

The `callbackCaptor.capture()` handles the capturing internally and might just return `null`. That seems to be the case here as well, while you actually require a non-null type. To work around this you can use the `capture(ArgumentCaptor<T>)` function of *mockito-kotlin*, which makes sure to not return `null`:

```
verify(interactor,times(1)).signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    "test4@gmail.com",
    "asdasd",
    capture(callbackCaptor)
)
```

Comment: Excuse me, how I inititalize it in the @Before setup ? Thanks !

Comment: its giving me  Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

Comment: I never had this issue. But I usually use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`.

Comment: if I use that I get all my class with redLines telling me Expecting a top level declaration

Comment: I'm not sure. Some googleing showed up that you might need the  `dexmaker-mockito-inline` dependency as well.

Comment: where can I find it ? I have made a research also but couldnt find the solution

Comment: for some reason, I have been strugling with this since a week, it seems like kotlin is not working very well with mockito :( and I need to pass this test so bad to keep doing features but I cant find an answer to it

Comment: yes, I tried with it but after importing it and compiling, it throwing the same problem

Comment: Maybe `com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline:2.25.0` might work. It sets up a file making it easier to work with Mockito and Kotlin. If this doesn't work, could you ask another question with the _MockMaker_ issue? Providing the whole stack trace to identify the issue. The original issue was the one with the capture method returning null.

Comment: you mean replacing the mockito-kotlin library you posted above with the mockito-inline one ? and let the same code as the answer?

Comment: `dexmaker-mockito-inline` is an additional configuration for _Mockito_. You should add it to your dependencies and also use _mockito-kotlin_.